# How to check if Magento is on 404 page?

Tags: php, magento, routes, http-status-code-404

Is there a way to check from a block or template if the page you are located on is a 404?

Answer (score 10):

The 404 page is rendered by `Mage_Cms_IndexController::noRouteAction()` in a vanilla Magento installation, so you could try something like this:

```
$action = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName();
if ($action == 'noRoute'){
   //do some stuff
}
```

Comment: I want to modify my headers to show a 410 instead of 404 only in category/product pages. So which is the ideal position to put this code?